# Is the NodeMCU UART Rx buffer size editable?

Tags: lua, nodemcu

I'm using NodeMCU w/ SDK 1.5.1.

I put my webpage in Flash and use REQUIRE to access.

Doing this apparently has affected receiving data via serial.

I'm using `UART.on("data",'\n')` call back and I'm dropping data, which makes me think the buffer is 256, from the pattern I'm seeing.

If I lower my baud rate from 38400 to 9600 it is better, but still fails.

How can I increase Rx buffer size or improve serial input handling?

Comment: Can you add to your question with additional information on what you mean by "I put my webpage in Flash and use REQUIRE to access.", and what you see if you do and don't do this?

Comment: Is there any more feedback you need? If not I suggest you consider to accept the answer so that SO can mark this question as closed, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 0):

There's no parameter for buffer size in [`uart.setup()`](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/uart/#uartsetup) and none of the (pre-build) firmware config files in [`app/include/`](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/tree/master/app/include) give you this option. So, no, you can not configure the buffer size.